# CTE to remove duplicate data

Tags: sql-server, duplicates, common-table-expression

I have a table where the rows are duplicated. I would like to remove the duplicates and add a Composite Key to avoid duplicates.

```
;WITH myCTE (RowNumber, invoice_id, Invoice_Number, Organization_id, status, created_at) AS 
( 
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Invoice_Number ORDER BY invoice_id,  Invoice_Number DESC) AS RowNumber , 
        invoice_id, Invoice_Number, Organization_id,status, created_at 
    FROM  
        Invoice_Export
) 
SELECT * 
FROM myCTE 
WHERE Invoice_number LIKE '%-00%' 
ORDER BY invoice_id

select * from Invoice_Export

ALTER TABLE Invoice_Export ALTER COLUMN [Organization_id] NVARCHAR(36) NOT NULL
ALTER TABLE Invoice_Export ALTER COLUMN [Invoice_Number] NVARCHAR(15) NOT NULL

ALTER table Invoice_Export
ADD CONSTRAINT [Composite_Key_Invoice] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Organization_id, Invoice_Number)
```

Is there any other better approach for the same.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that 'invoice_id' is unique, so

```
DELETE FROM Invoice_Export duplicate
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Invoice_Export
  WHERE duplicate.invoice_id > Invoice_Export.invoice_id
  AND duplicate.Organization_id = Invoice_Export.Organization_id
  AND duplicate.Invoice_Number = Invoice_Export.Invoice_Number)
```

instead `PRIMARY KEY` you can use `UNIQUE` (after removing duplicates)

```
ALTER TABLE Invoice_Export
ADD CONSTRAINT UC_Invoice_Export UNIQUE (Organization_id, Invoice_Number);
```